# How do I write chinese charactes in ZipEntry?

Tags: java, character-encoding, zipoutputstream

I want to export a string(chinese text) to CSV file inside a zip file. Where do I need to set the encoding to UTF-8? Or what approach should I take (based on the code below) to display chinese characters in the exported CSV file?

This is the code I currently have.

```java
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(out, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        try {
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("chinese.csv");
            zipOut.putNextEntry(entry);
            zipOut.write("类型".getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            zipOut.close();
            out.close();
        }
```

Instead of "类型", I get "ç±»åž‹" in the CSV file.

Comment: There is a `getBytes(Charset charset)` method . See : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.nio.charset.Charset-

Comment: @Arnaud I tried  ```zipOut.write("类型".getBytes(UTF_8)); ``` and it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you definitely need to change `zipOut.write("类型".getBytes());` to `zipOut.write("类型".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));` Also, when you open your resultant CSV file, the editor might not be aware that the content is encoded in UTF-8. You may need to tell your editor that it is UTF-8 encoding. For instance, in Notepad, you can save your file with "Save As" option and change encoding to UTF-8. Also, your issue might be just wrong display issue rather than actual encoding. There is an Open Source Java library that has a utility that converts any String to Unicode Sequence and vice-versa. This utility helped me many times when I was working on diagnosing various charset related issues. Here is the sample what the code does

```
result = "Hello World";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The output of this code is:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064
Hello World
```

The library can be found at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.8/jar) or at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) It comes as maven artifact and with sources and javadoc

Here is javadoc for the class [StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html)

I tried your inputs and got this:

```
System.out.println(StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence("类型"));
System.out.println(StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence("ç±»åž‹"));
```

And the output was:

```
\u7c7b\u578b
\u00e7\u00b1\u00bb\u00e5\u017e\u2039
```

So it looks like you did lose the info, and it is not just a display issue

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was a problem with my editor

Answer (score 1):

The `getBytes()` method is one culprit, without an explicit charset it takes the default character set of your machine. As of the Java [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String)) documentation:

> [`getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes())
>   Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's **default charset**, storing the result into a new byte array.
>
> [`getBytes(string charsetName)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String))
>   Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the **given charset**, storing the result into a new byte array.

Furthermore, as @Slaw pointed out, make sure that you [compile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options) (`javac -encoding <encoding>`) your files with the same encoding the files are in:

> **-encoding** Set the source file encoding name, such as EUC-JP and UTF-8. If -encoding is not specified, the platform default converter is used.

A call to `closeEntry()` was missing in the OP btw. I stripped the snippet down to what I found necessary to achieve the desired funcitonality.

```
    try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("out.zip");
         ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fileOut)) {
        zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("chinese.csv"));
        zipOut.write("类型".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        zipOut.closeEntry();
    }
```

Finally, as @MichaelGantman pointed out, you might want to check what is in which encoding using a tool like a hex-editor for example, also to rule out that the editor you view the result file in displays correct utf-8 in a wrong way. ["类"](https://graphemica.com/%E7%B1%BB) in utf-8 is (hex) `e7 b1 bb` in utf-16 (the java default encoding) it is `7c 7b`

Comment: I tried  ```zipOut.write("类型".getBytes(UTF_8)); ``` and it still does not work.

Comment: @IsaiaBejan Is your source file saved _and compiled_ using UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @curiosa It's a string literal. In this case, if you don't save the source file using UTF-8 then the characters are not saved correctly. Then you have to tell `javac` to use UTF-8 otherwise it won't read the characters correctly when compiling the code (e.g. `javac -encoding UTF-8 ...`).

Comment: thanks for the answer, apparently it was a problem with the editor, in notepad it was displayed correctly.